# TensorFlow OutOfRangeError FIFOQueue '_1_batch/fifo_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am desperately trying to find the error in my program. I consistently get the following error:

```
[[Node: input_producer/limit_epochs/CountUpTo = CountUpTo[T=DT_INT64, _class=["loc:@input_producer/limit_epochs/epochs"], limit=1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](input_producer/limit_epochs/epochs)]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/home/user/.conda/envs/tf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1039, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "/media/home/user/.conda/envs/tf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1021, in _run_fn
    status, run_metadata)
  File "/media/home/user/.conda/envs/tf/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 89, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)
  File "/media/home/user/.conda/envs/tf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 466, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
    pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.OutOfRangeError: FIFOQueue '_1_batch/fifo_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 3, current size 0)
         [[Node: batch = QueueDequeueUpToV2[component_types=[DT_FLOAT], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](batch/fifo_queue, batch/n)]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_tfr.py", line 60, in <module>
    res = sess.run(item_cont_b)
  File "/media/home/user/.conda/envs/tf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 778, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/media/home/user/.conda/envs/tf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 982, in _run
    feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
  File "/media/home/user/.conda/envs/tf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1032, in _do_run
    target_list, options, run_metadata)
  File "/media/home/user/.conda/envs/tf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1052, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.OutOfRangeError: FIFOQueue '_1_batch/fifo_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 3, current size 0)
         [[Node: batch = QueueDequeueUpToV2[component_types=[DT_FLOAT], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](batch/fifo_queue, batch/n)]]

Caused by op 'batch', defined at:
  File "test_tfr.py", line 48, in <module>
    allow_smaller_final_batch=True)
  File "/media/home/user/.conda/envs/tf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/input.py", line 917, in batch
    name=name)
  File "/media/home/user/.conda/envs/tf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/input.py", line 710, in _batch
    dequeued = queue.dequeue_up_to(batch_size, name=name)
  File "/media/home/user/.conda/envs/tf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/data_flow_ops.py", line 499, in dequeue_up_to
    self._queue_ref, n=n, component_types=self._dtypes, name=name)
  File "/media/home/user/.conda/envs/tf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_data_flow_ops.py", line 1420, in _queue_dequeue_up_to_v2
    timeout_ms=timeout_ms, name=name)
  File "/media/home/user/.conda/envs/tf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 768, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/media/home/user/.conda/envs/tf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2336, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/media/home/user/.conda/envs/tf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1228, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()

OutOfRangeError (see above for traceback): FIFOQueue '_1_batch/fifo_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 3, current size 0)
         [[Node: batch = QueueDequeueUpToV2[component_types=[DT_FLOAT], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](batch/fifo_queue, batch/n)]]
```

I am using TF version 1.1.0, the tfrecords-FIle is 40GB large and contains 1.6M examples. My script (as below) is in the same folder as **201704_test.tfrecords** which I am trying to read from. Current batch size, capacity and loop-range are just arbitrarily chosen for testing. Trying a few things mentioned across GitHub and StackOverFlow I keep getting stuck here.

**My Script**

```
import os
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

def read_and_decode(filename_queue):

    reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
    _, serialized_example = reader.read(filename_queue)

    features = tf.parse_single_example(
        serialized_example,
        features={
            'user': tf.FixedLenFeature([1], tf.int64),
            'item': tf.FixedLenFeature([1], tf.int64),
            'week': tf.FixedLenFeature([1], tf.int64),
            'label': tf.FixedLenFeature([1], tf.int64),
            'item_cont': tf.FixedLenFeature([6], tf.float32),
            'item_cat': tf.FixedLenFeature([3092], tf.float32),
            'user_cont': tf.FixedLenFeature([12], tf.float32),
            'user_cat': tf.FixedLenFeature([3138], tf.float32)
        }
    )

    user = features['user']
    item = features['item']
    week = features['week']
    label = features['label']
    item_cont = features['item_cont']
    item_cat = features['item_cat']
    user_cont = features['user_cont']
    user_cat = features['user_cat']

    return user, item, week, label, item_cont, item_cat, user_cont, user_cat


filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(['201704_test.tfrecords'],
                                                num_epochs=1)
user, item, week, label, item_cont, item_cat, user_cont, user_cat = \
                                read_and_decode(filename_queue=filename_queue)

item_cont_b = tf.train.batch([item_cont],
                              batch_size=3,
                              num_threads=1,
                              capacity=32,
                              enqueue_many=False,
                              shapes=None,
                              dynamic_pad=False,
                              allow_smaller_final_batch=True)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)

    for step in range(100000):
        if coord.should_stop():
            break
        res = sess.run(item_cont_b)
        print(res)

    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)
```

**Thanks for any helpful advice!**

Comment: I think setting `num_epochs=None` in the function `string_input_producer` will resolve the problem.

Comment: Thanks, but in fact it didn't - though the Traceback changed a bit, but still reaching at an OutOfRangeError

Comment: is it possible to share a snippet of the data / anonymized so that we can reproduce the error? that will be easier

Comment: I need to correct myself ;)
You were partially right, you can either set `num_epochs=None` or you need to initialized it correctly since it's a local variable and thus one needs to add `sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())` in order to accept a value for num_epochs.

In my case this issue was covered by something rather banal. After correcting for num_epochs I got an issue with unmatching dimensions which was quite clear and thus easy to fix. Thank You!